# VS Code doesn't have a HTML language mode after 1.24.1 update

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, emmet

I seem to have a problem after I updated to a new version of VS Code (1.24.1). VS Code isn't recognising HTML and isn't coloring/highlightning the HTML syntax. Emmet doesn't work, linter ... nothing. It seems like overall that there is not support just for HTML. CSS works, so does the JS, PHP...

Is it going to be fixed with the next update or I messed up with some of my settings?

[Screenshot of my VS Code window -- not highlighting HTML syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr1QM.png)

Answer (score 1):

In the bottom right you see `Plain Text` just click on it and select `HMTL`. I guess this will not only fix highlighting but emmet as well. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_changing-the-language-for-the-selected-file

Comment: I did that. I showed it on the screenshot, if I type HTML there are only 2 options:
Configure file association for '.html'... , and
Search Marketplace extensions for '.html'...

Comment: @MuhammedHalilović also no errors shown in terminal/ console?

Comment: Yeah, no problems. I tried the new update on my laptop and everything is fine - there IS a HTML language mode/support. 
I tried reinstalling it but that didn't help.